# Building a library with public and private modules using require.js

Tags: requirejs, rjs

I am working on a library built using require.js. It has a number of public (documented and accessible by the library users) and private (used only within the library) modules.
This is what I want to achieve during rjs optimization:

- compress my code into as few files as possible;
- all public modules must be accessible in individual files;
- no code should be duplicated between files.

Let's say I have modules A, B, C and D. A and B are public and both depend on C. C depends on D, but neither C nor D are part of the public API. I want rjs to create the following files:

- A.js -- contains A module
- B.js -- contains B module
- C.js -- contains both C and D modules

There is a way to achieve this in rjs config:

```
"modules": [
    {
        "name": "A",
        "exclude": ["C"]
    },
    {
        "name": "B",
        "exclude": ["C"]
    },
    {
        "name": "C"
    }
]
```

However, this requires me to keep track of all dependencies between modules, and as the library size grows, configuration file becomes error-prone and hard to maintain. Is there a way to just specify a list of public modules without their dependencies and expect the behavior described above?

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in a new feature in Require.JS 2.1.10: bundles.
http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles

Comment: Sounds like an interesting feature, however, it still doesn't save me from having to track dependencies in the configuration file. I could also put all modules into a single bundle, but I want to load only the modules I need.